# JQuery 1.7+ plugin for character countdown for a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been looking at JQuery plugins for counting down characters in a text area. I've seen quite a few, but they're all pretty old and most don't work with the latest JQuery.

Which JQuery character countdown plugins support JQuery 1.7+?

Comment: Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Not a good topic for an SO question. However, here's one. http://keith-wood.name/maxlength.html

Comment: I believe it's a fair question. It's not subjective -- I'm asking for specific information.

Comment: keith wood's maxlength plugin was written for jQuery 1.3.2, but it works in all versions of jQuery. Old isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: These plugins are dead simple to write; if you have one that doesn't work with 1.7, you could either fix it or write your own.

Comment: Sure it's easy to write, but why waste time writing something (with color coding, countdown, etc) that already exists.